# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() *subtraction*

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to make a small calculation by subtracting a variables number from 4

```
number_1_raw = random.randrange(1, 1000)
number_1_len = len(number_1_raw)
number_of_zeros = 4 - number_1_len
print("0" * number_of_zeros + number_1_raw)
```

I wanted the script to give me an answer that ranged from 1-3, however the 
code isn't executing properly.

The desired output would be something like this:
0617 or 0071 or 0008, etc.

Please help with this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant call len on an integer.

> The len() function returns the number of items in an object.
>   When the object is a string, the len() function returns the number of
>   characters in the string.

so what you can do is

> `number_1_len = len(str(number_1_raw))`

str changes int type to string type.

Answer (score 0):

This line `number_1_len = len(number_1_raw)`  is problem. You are getting an integer value as number_1_len,  and it has length of one. This number_1_len is actually the number of zeros that you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
import random

number_1_raw = random.randrange(1, 1000)
number_1_len = len(str(number_1_raw))
number_of_zeros = 4 - number_1_len
print(number_of_zeros)
result = "0" * number_of_zeros

print(result+str(number_1_raw))
```

Output

```
1            # number of zeros
0801
```

**What's wrong with your code**

You are trying to find length of an integer `number_1_raw` which is giving you the error as you need iterables or string to find a length of that object. First convert it into string and then use `len` on it.

Furthermore, in `print` statement you need to convert `number_1_raw` into string so that it can be appended. You can not perform `+` operation on `str` and `int`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I need to understand better what is happening...

Fist

```
number_1_raw = random.randrange(1, 1000)
```

The random.randrange returns a number, probably int.

Second

```
number_1_len = len(number_1_raw)
```

Has a problem, because number_1_raw is an int and len is a function that counts the number of elements from an array, an object... but number_1_len isn't... that's an int and len can't count an int element...

Is important you show all which error you're getting... and explain better what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

**I added the str() in a specific line so that your code runs without any error**

```
import random
number_1_raw = str(random.randrange(1, 1000)) #I added the str() in this line
number_1_len = len(number_1_raw)
number_of_zeros = 4 - number_1_len
print("0" * number_of_zeros + number_1_raw)
```

it is completely your code except that modified line bro.
You had coded well bro but a small datatype mistake only you can rectify them as you learn.
i hope this is useful :)